# Destructuring sequelize models based on filename

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, sequelize.js

How can I destructure and access my sequelize models based on their file names?

Setup:

```
/models
  index.js
  User.js
```

index.js:

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
const options = {
  operatorsAliases,
  host: envConfig.host,
  dialect: envConfig.dialect
};

const sequelize = new Sequelize(envConfig.database, envConfig.username, envConfig.password, options);

fs.readdirSync(__dirname).filter(file => {
  return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== 'index.js') && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
}).forEach(file => {
  let model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
  db[model.name] = model;
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

export default db;
```

User.js

```
export default (sequelize, dataTypes) => {
  return sequelize.define('User', {
    email: {
      type: dataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    passwordDigest: {
      type: dataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  });
};
```

Currently, I can do this to access `.create()`

```
import models from '../models/index';

console.log(models.User.create.toString());
/*
create(values, options) {
    options = Utils.cloneDeep(options || {});

    return this.build(values, {
      isNewRecord: true,
      attributes: options.fields,
      include: options.include,
      raw: options.raw,
      silent: options.silent
    }).save(options);
  }
*/
```

But I want to be able to do this

```
import { User } from '../models';

User.create({stuff: 1});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use destructuring if you do an `export default`.

I would recommend doing it like [this](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/3049#issuecomment-286205548):

```
import models from '../models';
const {User} = models;

User.create({stuff: 1});
```

But you can also define your models like:

```
const models = (sequelize, dataTypes) => {
  return sequelize.define('User', {
    email: {
      type: dataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    passwordDigest: {
      type: dataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  });
};

export const User = models.User;
```

and then use it as you wanted.